# Description of Koszul dual of Sklyanin algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, cohomology, koszul-algebras

It is well-known that Sklyanin algebras are Koszul, but, is it known an explicit description of the dual algebra Ext_A(k,k)? (I mean in terms of generators and relations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 10 of the following paper spells out this example.

*Smith, S. Paul*, **Some finite dimensional algebras related to elliptic curves**, Bautista, Raymundo (ed.) et al., Representation theory of algebras and related topics. Proceedings of the workshop, Mexico City, Mexico, August 16-20, 1994. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society. CMS Conf. Proc. 19, 315-348 (1996). [ZBL0856.16009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0856.16009).

Comment: thank you very much! that was precisely what I was looking for!